# GLIBC not found on Flask App hosted on GoDaddy shared hosting

Tags: python, flask, web, backend, shared-hosting

When I access the hosted site via a url, I get an `Internal Server Error`. Here are the logs:

```
App 2425607 output: node: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.16' not found (required by node)
App 2425607 output: node: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.17' not found (required by node)
App 2425607 output: node: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.14' not found (required by node)
App 2425607 output: node: /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.14' not found (required by node)
App 2425607 output: node: /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.18' not found (required by node)
App 2425607 output: node: /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.19' not found (required by node)
App 2425607 output: node: /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.5' not found (required by node)
App 2425607 output: node: /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.15' not found (required by node)
App 2425607 output: nvm is not compatible with the npm config "prefix" option: currently set to ""
App 2425607 output: Run `nvm use --delete-prefix v15.11.0 --silent` to unset it.
```

What might be the reason and how to fix this?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Could you edit your question to include some additional info about your setup? The logs are related to a node.js part of your application, and not directly related to flask/python. Do you know why? Perhaps, you have some javascript files in the project directory?

Comment: Thank you Nikolay, I noticed that but didnt understand why it has a NodeJs warning, I dont have any js files in my project.